# How to display no record using ListView in Django?

Tags: python, django, listview, model, record

I'm using ListView to display objects of model but i want when there is no object in model so I display *No records or products*.
  What I need to do  write a  new function for it or there is any built-in function in ListView for this purpose.

**views.py**

```
class StockView(ListView):
    template_name = 'stock/stock.html'
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout this example, [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no athletes in this list.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `{% empty %}` what that's meaning??@bmons

Comment: @AdilIjaz it's an django's internal template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

Answer (score 0):

you can use `default_if_none`
for example:

```
{{ value|default_if_none:"default_msg" }}
```

If value is None, the output will be default_msg.

for more details check [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)